# Joomla 3 - How to get value from configuration file?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm building a custom component and I just want to get a value from the global config in my controller. I can't find any information about how to do this.

Something like...

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$this->_db = $config->get('db');
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation on how to do it is slightly outdated:

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getConfig

But if you check the code they actually drop the ampersand function:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_users/models/registration.php

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$fromname = $config->get('fromname');
```

Also if you are trying to connect to the database you really can just use the DB object from JFactory.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

Learn more about properly connecting to the database here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 5):

Since Joomla 3.2:

`JFactory::getApplication()->get($varname, $default);`

See the [reference](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/application/cms.php#L280-L294)

Comment: Reference is broken, but new link is here: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JFactory_class#JFactory::getConfig.28.29